# Internal server error on /v1.2/places endpoint sandbox

Tags: uber-api

> It seems sandbox doesn't support v1.2/places endpoint,

GET `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/places/home` -->

{
    "code": "internal_server_error",
    "message": "We have experienced a problem."
}

GET `https://api.uber.com/v1.2/places/home` -->

Works ok

> Also, I notice the Sandbox response is slower when my request is coming from AWS Lambda(Especially, GET `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/{request_id}`).
>   Do I need to do any setting for it?

Comment: From Review: Would you please edit you question and clarify what exactly "works ok" and what is not working? It is quite hard to understand what exactly is the problem. See: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Indeed that endpoint fails on the sandbox, and sandbox requests that reference a place rather than a location also fail